# PHP mysql_real_escape_string() and % character

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection, wildcard

What does `mysql_real_escape_string()` do with the `%` (percent) character and how much of a security risk does it represent (and how to fix it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`mysql_real_escape_string()` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> Note:  mysql_real_escape_string() does not escape % and _. These are
>   wildcards in MySQL if combined with
>   LIKE, GRANT, or REVOKE.

As far as security, unless you are running a `LIKE`, `GRANT`, or `REVOKE`, it's a non-issue. `LIKE` is probably the only *real* concern. It's up to you how you would want to escape it in these situations.

A quick example:

```
"... LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($string) . "%' ..."
```

Comment: How do you do the gray blocks without the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: @FinalForm, the first is a quote. The second is a code snippet. There are buttons for both on the edit form.

Comment: But how would it be a security risk? It can mess up the search but you could type asdfgjdfg in the search field and mess up the search that way.

Comment: If you're using `mysql_real_escape_string()` you've minimized the security risk. If a user enters `abc%def`, it's up to you how you handle it.

Answer (score 4):

It does not do nothing with % character. Why didn't you try it?

Comment: That only answers one third of my question. :)

Comment: I actually laughed out loud at this chain of comments. upvote just for that!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

> Note: mysql_real_escape_string() does not escape % and _. These are
>   wildcards in MySQL if combined with LIKE, GRANT, or REVOKE.