# PHP string replace to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, code-injection

I've design this small function and I would like to know if anyone thinks it's safe enough, or if not, why.

```
    function safeSQLI($INPUT){
      // Trim un-needed spaces
      $safe_input = trim($INPUT);

      // Replace any SQL commands
      $safe_input = str_ireplace("drop",    "", $safe_input);
      etc...

      // Escape the result
      $safe_input = mysql_real_escape_string($safe_input);

      // Return the "Safe" result
      return $safe_input;
}
```

**Answer:** No, it's not safe at all. I am now using PDO and I think I was missing something great before now.

Comment: Safe maybe, but you are quite restricting the words a user can use. Nobody will ever be able to drop the bass again.

Comment: **Side note:** you can pass arrays into `str_ireplace`: http://php.net/str_ireplace

Comment: `truncate`? `alter`? `rename`? `update`?

Comment: @user3390532 You should look at this question for possible security issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473823/php-mysql-real-escape-string-and-character

Comment: or this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) - it's really sad how many times per day I post this link :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a codereview, which is what http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for.

Comment: You know what's *even safer*? `$stmt->bind_param('s', $INPUT)`

Comment: Beats me how ppl can upvote comment for this that starts with "safe maybe". This is absolutely unsafe.

Comment: `mysql_stmt::bind_param()` must be called once, not once for each parameter. It's easier to use PDO, because then you can simply pass the $params array to `PDOStatement::execute()`.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('iss', $p1, $p2, $p3);
  ok so I would need to do something like this qith mysqli
is there a lot of difference between PDO and MySQLi?

Comment: Hi there. If you get an answer, please do not merge it into your question. New readers, such as myself, will have a rather confusing time working out what you mean by "Proof that it's not safe from: ntaso".

Comment: Alright sorry im new over here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_ireplace()` is generally a bad choice, because it doesn't work recursive. Try the following:

```
$safe_input = 'DELDELETEETE * FROM users';
```

Will result in:

```
DELETE * FROM users
```

So, your entire function falls back to `mysql_real_escape_string()` and everything that came before is useless. The point is: It's not impossible to write proper filtering methods, but it can be a real challenge to cover every single case there is.

You want to either follow a whitelisting approach and allow only certain types of content. This is tough to implement in the real world.

Or a blacklisting approach and deny certain characters. Most SQL injection vulnerabilites happen because one can inject additional commands in a string. If you escape the `'` (or use mysql_real_escape_string(), you are usually safe). However, it depends on your web app if additional filtering is required or not.

Or use prepared statements.

Comment: `DROP * FROM users` is not a valid SQL query. ITYM `DELETE * FROM users`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant

Comment: So I would need to make function that prepare my query and then for any query i would call those function passing it the inputs?

Comment: Read this, this is explains it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Using MySQLi or PDO I just wanted to know if I can make it shorter to use. Cause there's is sometime a lot of input parameters and I don't want to write 10 line of code for a single query everytime i need to execute a query. I posted an exemple of this in the EDIT section of my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

It does prevent injection, provided you use quotes like you should:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='$username'
```

For example.

However it is complete overkill. `mysql_real_escape_string` is sufficient to make an input safe, provided you use the quotes as above.

I spent all day today trying to get some database work done on a server that had been locked down to return "Not Acceptable" HTTP responses if "anything that looked like a database table name was present in the request". Needless to say, it took significantly longer than it needed to, when a simple `mysql_real_escape_string` would have sufficed.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) about the "safety" of `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @kingkero Did you miss the part where I made the need for quotes clear in my answer?

Comment: I think in the second answer of the posted link he uses quotes as well

Comment: @kingkero Ye-e-e-es... under extremely contrived circumstances that should be avoided by setting the character set appropriately.

Comment: Tbh I didn't fully read the linked post (neither did I downvote yours), thought it might be interesting in the context of safety

Comment: Don't understand the -1 here, and it has not been justified, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Not safe at all. Try running this:

```
 echo safeSQLI("drdropop tatableble TABLE_NAME");
```

Comment: Yeah the result was: drop table _NAME

Comment: @user3390532 Obviously your table name isn't literally `TABLE_NAME`

Comment: you best option is to use an established library. if you want to write your own, you'd be best of to split the query into its parts and then access them separately.

Answer (score -2):

That never let you insert a post about SQL in your blog.

I think use prepare statements and mysql_real_escape_string is safe enough.

PS: And you can avoid DDL sentences at BD level, with permissions.

Comment: Use one or the other - not both. That's the kind of thinking what got OP in this mess in the first place. Use *correct* escaping, not *excessive* escaping. It's like people who use `htmlspecialchars` for inserting...